# How do I get variables from my plugin's settings page?

Tags: plugin-development

I am currently working on a plugin, and I want to add a settings page. I've already found out how to create the settings page, but how do I get the content from the settings page into a variable so I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it a lot simpler than I though. When you use `register_setting("something", "name")` then to get it in the plugin, just use `get_option("name")`.

Answer (score 1):

In your options page each field should be put into an options array.  For Example:

When you registered your settings page you should have used a code like this:

```
register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'rt_fed_settings', 'rt_validate');
```

Once on your page where you want to call settings, use this code:

```
$options_fed = get_option('rt_fed_settings'); // this is calling your settings array into a variable called options_fed.
```

Now to call items from it you would call them just like any array items:

```
$options_fed['rt_fed_text_test_billing_field']
```

The array items were set in your plugins page, but if you want see what is in the code you can use print_r.

Comment: I used `register_setting("member_only_fields", "loginURL");`, so what would I use? `options = get_option("member_only_fields")` then `$options["loginURL"]`doesn't work

Comment: That seems right to me!

Comment: It returns nothing, but when I return to the settings page, it's still there, so its saving.